# Accessibility collectionView focus changes when reloaded, iOS

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, accessibility

I'm working on the accessibility of a calendar which is actually a collectionView. Whenever a cell is tapped, the collectionView will be reloaded by calling

```
[self.collectionView reloadData];
```

The problem is if the voiceOver is running, the focus will move to another place after the cell tapped because that cell is reused on somewhere else.

Is there anyway to keep the focus where it was after the reloadData? Thanks!

Comment: post a accessibility notification again to make the selected cell focus again

Comment: @Mr.T Thanks for your reply! I tried that way but the focus will move to the new place first and read the content of that cell then dragged back, which looks weird.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I lost count of hours trying to fix this

Answer (score 6):

Just find a workaround for this. The focus is changed because the focused cell is reused somewhere else when doing [colleciontView reloadData].

So if we reload the collectionViewCells one by one, that focused cell will not be used anywhere else. I call this method to reload the collectionView when VoiceOver is running.

```
- (void)reloadCalendarCollectionView {

  NSInteger items = [self.calendarItems count];

  for (NSInteger i = 0; i < items; i++) {
    [self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:1] ]];
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing `self.collectionView.accessibilityElementsHidden = YES` before reloading data. Then, when it completes, you will have to do the inverse & then post a notification for the cell you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Just tried it but it seems that function is not hiding the focus frame but makes your colleciontViewCells not accessible anymore.

Answer (score 0):

We have a collection view and this collection view reloading data in every second. When user taps cell, focus changing after every reload, so collectionview cell selects wrong cell at indexPath.

Create a protocol for delegation in cell:

```
protocol AccessibilityCellProtocol{

    func accessibilityFocused(cell:UICollectionViewCell)
   
}
```

Override accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused in your cell:

```
override class func accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused(){
    self.delegate.accessibilityFocused(cell:self)
}
```

In view controller create an selectedIndexPath variable. Assign it in delegation method.

```
func accesibilityFocused(cell:UITableViewCell){
    selectedIndex = collectionView.indexPath(for: cell)
}
```

And in your didSelectItemAtIndexPath method:

```
if UIAccessibility.isVoiceOverRunning{
    cellTappedWith(indexPath:selectedIndex)
    return
}
cellTappedWithIndexPath(indexPath:indexPath)
```

Comment: What is cellTappedWith(indexPath:)?

Comment: Your collectionviewcell selection action.